# Access CUDA global device variable from host

Tags: c++, cuda, global-variables

I was wondering if there is an official source, why the following works:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Array{
    int el[10000];
};

__device__ Array devAr;

void test(Array& ar = devAr){
    for(int i=0; i<10000; i++)
        ar.el[i] = i;
    std::cout << ar.el[0] + ar.el[9999] << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    test();
}
```

You get a warning "a __device__ variable "devAr" cannot be directly read in a host function" if you try to access devAr directly but through the reference there is no such warning (for good reason). But in both cases it is possible to access the variable from the host. So it seems, there is a host instance of that variable.

What I need to know: Can I take this for granted?

Other testcase showing the values of the pointers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

__device__ int devAr[2];

__global__ void foo(){
    printf("Device: %p\n", &devAr);
    devAr[0] = 1337;
}

int main()
{
    devAr[0] = 4;
    std::cout << devAr[0] << std::endl;
    void* ad;
    cudaGetSymbolAddress(&ad, devAr);
    std::cout << ad << " " << &devAr << std::endl;
    foo<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    int arHost[2];
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(arHost, devAr, sizeof(arHost), 0);
    std::cout << "values: " << arHost[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> 4
>   0x500bc0000 0x66153c
>   Device: 0x500bc0000
>   values: 1337

Comment: No, you can't take it for granted.  You are exploring UB.  There is no  specification or guarantee of the correctness of this code, even though it appears to "work".  However you got there, syntactically you are attempting to directly access a `__device__` variable in host code, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you are doing is invalid and you should listen to the warning:

> a `__device__` variable `devAr` cannot be directly read in a host function

First let me simplify your code a bit to only size necessary to show the issue:

```
#include <iostream>

__device__ int devAr[1];

int main()
{
    devAr[0] = 4;
    std::cout << devAr[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Now what is happening:

1. `__device__ int devAr[1];` allocates fixed size array in device memory and stores the pointer to this **device memory** inside the `devAr` variable (hence the warning).
2. The `devAr` address points to valid piece of device memory, however, such address can be used even in host code, because host and device memory use the addresses in the same format. However, in host code `devAr` points to some random **uninitialized piece of host memory**.
3. Based on above one can say that `devAr[0] = 4;` just writes `4` into some random uninitialized location in host memory.

Try running the following code, perhaps it will help you understand what is happening under the hood:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

__device__ int devAr[1];

__global__ void foo()
{
    printf("dev: %d \n", devAr[0]);
    devAr[0] = 5;
    printf("dev: %d \n", devAr[0]);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "host: " << devAr[0] << endl;
    devAr[0] = 4;
    cout << "host: " << devAr[0] << endl;

    foo << <1, 1 >> >();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cout << "host: " << devAr[0] << endl;
}
```

Output is going to be:

```
host: 0
host: 4
dev: 0
dev: 5
host: 4
```

**UPDATE:**

After clarifying what you are asking in the below comments I started digging in the issue and found couple of related SO threads, most of the quotations come from the comments below the answers, here they are:

1. [cudaMemcpy() vs cudaMemcpyFromSymbol()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14817801/3242721):

   > any statically defined device symbol (`__device__`, `__constant__`, even textures) results in the toolchain emitting two symbols, one in the device module, the other in the host object. The CUDA runtime sets up and maintains a dynamic mapping between these two symbols. The symbol API calls are the way of retrieving this mapping for `__constant__` and `__device__` symbols. The texture APIs retrieve the mapping for the texture symbols, etc.
2. [Usage of global vs. constant memory in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6038335/3242721):

   > `*PNT` is a `__device__` variable, not a host variable containing the address of a device variable. (Confusing, I know.) Therefore if you try to access it on the host as with `(void**)&PNT` you are trying to read a device variable from the host which is not permitted. From the host code point of view it's just a symbol, so you need to use `cudaGetSympolAddress()` to store the device address in a host variable that you can then pass to `cudaMemcpyToSymbol()`, as @talonmies shows.
3. [CUDA Constant Memory Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19218101/3242721):

   > Somewhat confusingly, A and B in host code are not valid device memory addresses. They are host symbols which provide hooks into a runtime device symbol lookup. It is illegal to pass them to a kernel- If you want their device memory address, you must use `cudaGetSymbolAddress` to retrieve it at runtime.
4. [cudaMemcpyToSymbol vs. cudaMemcpy why is it still around (cudaMemcpyToSymbol)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15985093/3242721):

   > A copy to that address via the CUDA API would fail with an invalid argument error because it isn't an address in GPU memory space that the API had previously allocated. And yes, this applies to generic `__device__` pointers and statically declared device symbols as well.
5. [cudaMemcpyFromSymbol on a `__device__` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26076298/3242721):

   > The root of the problem is that you are not allowed to take the address of a device variable in ordinary host code: ... Although this seems to compile correctly, the actual address passed is garbage. To take the address of a device variable in host code, we can use `cudaGetSymbolAddress`

Based on this evidence let me try to update my original 3step explanation from above:

1. `__device__ int devAr[1];` allocates fixed size array in device memory and stores "hooks into a runtime device symbol lookup" into the host version of `devAr` variable (see linked resources 1 and 3).
2. The `devAr` address is just a garbage from host's point of view and should only be used with the symbol API calls, such as `cudaGetSymbolAddress` (all of the linked resources appear to support this theory) because it maps to the device version of `devAr` variable.

I was not able to come up with anything "more concrete" such as link to CUDA documentation but I hope this is now clear enough. All in all it seems like you now have a guarantee for the behavior described above (i.e. there is a host and device version of `devAr` variable) but to me it rather appears as an implementation detail which you should not rely on and should not use host version of `devAr` variable for purposes other than symbol API calls.

Comment: I'm completely aware that I cannot change the device contents of the variable from host. But you can show via `cudaGetSymbolAddress` that the device and host address are different (pretty sure, that the same holds true for the address in the kernel) So from all points it doesn't seem like a pointer to a random chunk but a host-copy of the struct. I wasn't able to find evidence, that it is indeed a random chunk of memory and hence an invalid host pointer.

Comment: I added a code example for showing that the pointers on host and device are not the same. Only that one gotten by `cudaGetSymbolAddress` is the one on the device

Comment: Ok so it seems to be an implementation detail and just happens to work. Interesting: If you declare 2 device variables, their (host) addresses actually support the assumption that they are valid host allocations. If you change the size of the first, the others address moves further away so that the space between those 2 is correctly the size of the first.